# Cannot connect to Tor Browser anymore

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, connection

I have used Tor browser for years with now problems at all.
When i try it now  it says that the proxy is missing (and/or network which is working well) and to contact Tor itself.

Gives me this error message:

```
24/03/2019 16:32:02.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
24/03/2019 16:32:02.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
24/03/2019 16:32:02.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
24/03/2019 16:32:02.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
24/03/2019 16:32:03.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
24/03/2019 16:32:03.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
24/03/2019 16:32:03.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
24/03/2019 16:32:03.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:03.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop3' (fresh): $8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E~ndnop3 at 109.105.109.165 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:04.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
24/03/2019 16:32:06.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
24/03/2019 16:32:06.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
24/03/2019 16:32:06.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
24/03/2019 16:32:06.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Can anyone help? I know that the 'disablenetwork' thing is set but i have no clue about how to fix any of this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

late 2006, Intel iMac 10.6.8.,

Answer (score 0):

That is a red herring and not an actual error:

> Tor Browser sets DisableNetwork (which prevents just the tor daemon from making outgoing network connections) when it first starts up to prevent an unconfigured tor daemon from making connections, but will unset it once it's satisfied that the user has had the opportunity to configure things.
>   This happens on each launch, regardless of if the bridge configuration UI is displayed.
>   Unless you have been messing with the tor daemon's configuration in fairly exotic and non-standard ways, any and all messages related to DisableNetwork are expected parts of the Tor Browser startup process, and should be ignored.

I would suggest deleting all versions of Tor on your machine and redownloading the latest version from the tor project website at https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

Comment: I don't know much about Tor except that it works.

Comment: (I keep pressing enter to shift lines!) It's always worked perfectly. I don't meess with its insides. I wouldnt know where to start. I have deleted it several times and installed it again from Time Machine but still the same. I have old OSX, 10.6.8 and i can't update it any more so the newest verson of Tor won't install. I have found sites with older versions but still they give me same result. I will thoroughly delete the old and install best version i can find and see how it goes. Thanks again.